# Get the list of files that has change-puppet

Tags: jira, puppet

We have our Jira managed by puppet, so we have puppet script to install lira.So after installation we have few file like server.xml,setting.sh manually changed in the server without using puppet.

So we need to commit the changes done back to puppet repo(r10k managed).But how will we identify the files which have changes compared to files in puppet .

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be changing files manually on the server and committing them back into puppet.

> But how will we identify the files which have changes compared to files in puppet .

You can't.

This fundamentally breaks the idea of infrastructure as code and configuration management. The whole idea of putting your configuration data into puppet is to *stop* this behaviour so that multiple people can always know what has changed because the changes are tracked in version control.

Make all the changes inside a git repo and then test them using a Puppet run, potentially with `--noop` if you're worried this may break JIRA.

You need to get a workflow set up so that this is easy, not continue to manipulate files on a server by hand and then expect Puppet to understand what each person has done.

Comment: Thanks for replying.I tied to do a dryrun in but it didnt give me the files changed.

Comment: used this command puppet agent -t —environment <folder_name> —noop